# Косая сажень и прочие сажени - куда падает ударение?

Tags: ударение

Если брать собственно слово *сажень*, то ударение в нём вариативно: саже́нь и са́жень. А как ставить ударение в выражениях:

- *погонная сажень*
- *квадратная сажень*
- *кубическая сажень*
- *печатная сажень*
- *маковая сажень*
- *косая сажень*

Первые пять после перехода на метрическую систему из обихода вышли, а вот *косая сажень* - сохранилась. И понимания нет.

В "Большом толковом словаре русского языка" (гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов) ударение в выражении падает на Е: [косая сажЕнь](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?bts=x&word=%F1%E0%E6%E5%ED%FC).

Однако 23 мая 2012 г. в передаче ["Словарь ударений"](https://vk.com/search?c%5Bq%5D=словарь%20ударений%20косая%20сажень&c%5Bsection%5D=audio) на "Радио 7" эксперт портала gramota.ru Владимир Пахомов сказал, что ударение ставится только на А: *косая сАжень*.

1. Чему верить?
2. Как ставить ударение в первых пяти словосочетаниях?

Answer (score 1):

ИНФОРМАЦИЯ ИЗ ГРАММАТИКИ-80

Существительное 3-его скл.  "сажЕнь"  (старинная русская мера длины) имеет   также форму "сАжень", при этом две формы относятся к РАЗНЫМ АКЦЕНТНЫМ КЛАССАМ.

Первая форма  "сажЕнь" имеет  постоянное ударение на основе во всех падежах единственного и множественного числа, например:  одна сажЕнь,  несколько сажЕней,  попадал в цель в пяти сажЕнях.

Для формы "сАжень" характерен переход ударения на окончание в косвенных падежах множественного числа:  саженЕй, саженЯх, саженЯми.

В Р.падеже, кроме основной формы "саженЕй", используется более распространенная форма "сАжен" с вариантным нулевым окончанием.  Таким образом, в И. п. используются ДВЕ ФОРМЫ с окончанием И: сажЕни и сАжени, а в Р. падеже можно встретить ТРИ ФОРМЫ: несколько  сажЕней, сАжен и саженЕй.

Словарь ударений (2010 год)дает два варианта: сажЕнь и сАжень. В устойчивом обороте: косая сАжень в плечах, другое ударение определяется как  отклонение от литературной нормы. Судя по общей тенденции, основной считается форма "сажЕнь", ее следует использовать в нейтральном стиле. В то же время разговорный и поэтический язык не отказывается и от второй формы.

Примеры из литературы: Твардовский: Грядка лука в огороде, САжень улицы в селе. Пушкин: Он, правда, в туз из пистолета в пяти сажЕнях попадал. Но (Цветаева): Ростом-то - башня, в плечах-то косая сажЕнь.

Answer (score 1):

Я не слышал этой передачи, полагаю, Владимир тут и еще в нескольких случаях ошибся.

Я сейчас не дам дополнительных ссылок (см. Софию, там все изложено), но если отвечать конкретно на Ваш вопрос, то я с ней разойдусь. В устоявшихся выражениях типа "косая сажень в плечах" ударение не должно меняться по общему принципу, ибо такие выражения обычно утрачивают связь с конкретным объектом, становятся как бы самостоятельной единицей языка - и потому сохраняют исходную форму.   Т.е. тут однозначно "косая саж**е**нь в плечах".

В доказательство могу привести только Лопатина с Кузнецовым, но сразу предупреждаю, что в данном вопросе не считаю их б**о**льшими авторитетами с сравнении со специализированными словарями.
http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?all=x&word=%25F1%25E0%25E6%25E5%25ED%25FC

Я бы соотнес этот подход и вообще со всеми единицами измерений, вами упомянутыми. Меры эти ушли в прошлое и должны сохранять свою форму. Т.е. и тут предпочтительно саж**е**нь: косая саж**е**нь, квадратная саж**е**нь - и проч.

Во всех остальных случаях, т.е. в современном употреблении с**а**жень и саж**е**нь конкурируют, причем последняя форма постепенно вытесняется первой. Видимо, это и имел в виду Пахомов.